# Undefined object when parsing from JSON - React

Tags: json, reactjs

Not sure if this is obvious or not, but please point this out if it is. **I am not an expert in React, but merely trying to learn to the best of my ability **

I am trying to change a json into an object so I can actively parse through its text for output onto my webpage. Before, on regular JS,HTML, CSS I attempted this as  such...

```js
// getting the json file and reading from it
$.getJSON(...., function (tool) {

...
 
    myHTML += '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">';
 
    
    
     myHTML += '<h3>Name: ' + tool.items[i].name + '</h3>';
     
     ...
```

This snippet ran fine and I was able to treat the json as a pure object parsing out what I needed inside. However, I cannot replicate this in react. **Again, I am not an expert in react. **

```js
export class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {apiInfo: 'default', test: []};
      //  this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
  }
 
  componentDidMount() {
    const that = this; // think of this as a promise request that is fufilled out
    fetch(...)
        .then(function(response) { //changes the object to a json object
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(jsonData) {
            // this.setState({ test: jsonObject });
            return JSON.stringify(jsonData);
            
            console.log(jsonData);
        })
        .then(jsonStr => { // same as the then(function etc, taking in the previous object
        
          this.setState({ apiInfo: jsonStr });
          jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

          // console.log(apiInfo);
          console.log(jsonStr);
          console.log(jsonObject)
          console.log(jsonObject.ipads[1])
  

      });
     
}

  render(){
      return(
              <div>
                  <h1>{JSON.stringify.toString(jsonObject.ipads[1])}</h1>
                  <p>{this.state.apiInfo}</p>
              </div>
      );
  }

}
```

I can clearly stringfy the json to make it print out the entire JSON and use console.log to call for parts of the json. Clearly, the object jsonObject is being filled. However again, I am not sure why I cannot replicate the same method of "item.tool[i].name..." in react. Thoughts?

Comment: Feel free to ask for more info or clarification. I tried to explain this problem without giving away too much information since this is a private project. I will try my best.

Comment: Run through creating a [mcve], because that will (1) remove anything that's even remotely private, and (2) in 99% of the cases lets you discover the problem on your own. But if it doesn't, you now have perfect, generic, safe code to show in your post.

Comment: Sadly this is about as minimal that I can get it to and couldn't find the solution. Again, I can try explaining my issue further when I get back to my computer. But this is the best that I can show as of now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the scope of your `render` method there is no object called `jsonObject`.
Change your code in `render` to this,

```
render(){
      const {apiInfo}=this.state;
      const jsonObject=JSON.parse(apiInfo);
      return(
              <div>
                  <h1>{JSON.stringify(jsonObject.ipads[1])}</h1>
                  <p>{apiInfo}</p>
              </div>
      );
  }
```

On a further note, with regard to your logic(not functionality),

- I don't understand why you need to stringify the JSON to store it in the state? You could store it as it is.
- What are you trying to do with this code `JSON.stringify.toString(jsonObject.ipads[1])`? Calling `toString()` on `JSON.stringify()` will always give the value `function stringify() { [native code] }` which is definitely not what you want.